# Fetch key from String

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

Below is the method implemented currently to fetch all the teacherID and store in a list

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetId(string id)
{
  var teacherID= new List<string>();
                                    
  var responseMessage = @"[
  { 'id': '100','studentId': '001','studentName': 'TestStudent1'},
  {'id': '101','studentId': '002','teacherId': '100','studentName': 'TestStudent2'},
  {'id': '102','studentId': '003','teacherId': '101','studentName': 'TestStudent3'}]";

  var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(responseMessage);

  foreach (var id in jsonObj)
  {
       var Id = id["teacherId"];
       teacherID.Add(Id.ToString());
  }         

 return teacherID;
}
```

I am getting exception beacause in the first list teacherId is not present.
Can any body help me out with this.

Comment: You can try TryGetValue. If some key is not there it will not throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use null check before adding. If key does not exist then null will be returned.

```
 foreach (var tid in jsonObj)
   {
       var Id = tid["teacherId"];
       if(null!=Id)
        {
           teacherID.Add(Id.ToString());
         }
   }
```

Also, method parameter and variable in foreach has same name "id". This will not work.
I have changed this in foreach loop.

Comment: No error will be thrown. NULL will be returned.

Comment: Amit is right, this will not throw an exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9MEZo - although TryGetValue would be the more elegant solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TryGetValue

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj)
{
    if (obj.TryGetValue("teacherId", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, out var teacherId))
    {
        teacherIds.Add(((string)teacherId));
    }
}
```

Or a null check:

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj)
{
    if(obj["teacherId"] != null) 
    {
        teacherIds.Add(obj["teacherId"].ToString());
    }
}
```

However, since you seem to have a well structured response, why not do a strongly typed deserilization:

```
class MyViewModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; } 
}

var responseMessage = @"[
    { 'id': '100','studentId': '001','studentName': 'TestStudent1'},
    {'id': '101','studentId': '002','teacherId': '100','studentName': 'TestStudent2'},
    {'id': '102','studentId': '003','teacherId': '101','studentName': 'TestStudent3'}]";
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyViewModel>>(responseMessage);
            
var teacherIds = response.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TeacherId))
    .Select(x => x.TeacherId)
    .ToList();
```